# Why is my fav icon not showing in mobile search result?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, favicon

Right now I've noticed that my icon is not showing in mobile search result. Only thing that is showing is pale blue earth icon thingy. It is perfectly fine on desktop tabs.

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/cropped-site-icon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/cropped-site-icon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/cropped-site-icon-180x180.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/cropped-site-icon-270x270.png" />
```

I have also checked on `https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=website.com`
and the icon is there. It has been almost 3 months since this particular website is live, I tought aswell that it will show up after some time, but no luck.
I am clueless on how to debug this , anyone?

Comment: I use this plugin for that purpose - works really well: https://wordpress.org/plugins/favicon-by-realfavicongenerator/

Comment: I'm not really a fan of plugins , I prefer to do things manually because I have more control over it and if something breaks I know exactly what I've done.

Comment: But you are using Wordpress, so there's a lot of stuff which you don't have control over... ;-) (I also write my own themes to avoid unnecessary overload, but for certain things plugins are very useful and can save me a lot of work)

Comment: Haha, agreed I also use gtranslate for saving me alot of work. God bless small websites that don't require 100% true translation and that plugin but on topic if I dont figure favicon problem in the next few days I'm definetly gonna give that plugin a shot

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and still no luck, did you finally solve it somehow?

Comment: No still nothing, I tried what the answer below said and no luck and I also installed the plugin Johannes suggested and still nothing. . . Though icon is showing in duckduckgo search result so I am guessing google is the problem

Answer (score 0):

If your Favicon meets the requirements listed at : https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/favicon-in-search#guidelines.
Then,

- Try clearing the cache,
- Or add URL parameter like: `?v=2` or simply `?` and re-index the page.